# jQuery bounce effect not working for links in an un-ordered list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-effects, bounce

I'm having trouble getting the bounce effect to work.  animate() works as long as the anchor tag is relatively positioned.  I made a jsfiddle with all of my css and html from my site available here:  http://jsfiddle.net/CRzFj/

I'm looking for a result similar to http://jsfiddle.net/RGvjj/26/  but I think one of my css styles is breaking the bounce.  I'm not sure which one it is though.

**EDIT
Actually found the answer to this shortly after posting, and playing around with the jsfiddle.  I needed to add position: relative and display: block to the span tags, removing float: left.**

```
.nav ul.primary-menu li a span {
    //float: left;
    height: 198px;
    line-height: 335px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    // new code here
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to add span so just do this

```
$("#primary-menu-bar ul.menu li a span").hover(function() {
    $(this).effect("bounce", { times: 3 }, 300);
});
```